# how to check fields are exits or not in database using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

I want to input date in date format(dd/mm/yyyy). I want to check the date field are unique. and it will not able to save in database.

I got problem the duplicate record also saved in my database table
my input field is:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="NewspaperDate" name="NewspaperDate" />
```

and my validation is

```
$rules = array(
            'NewspaperDate' => 'unique:newspaper,date',
            'PublishDate' => 'required',
            'NoOfPages' => 'required'
        );
```

Comment: Is your Table name `newspaper`  and coloumn name `NewspaperDate` ?

Comment: yes .....and date is saved in database in yy/mm/dd format

Comment: Your Rule is good enough, You shall set unique in the database for the particular field and check it once

Comment: thanks , it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Table Name is `newspaper` and coloumn name is `NewspaperDate` according to your rule

```
$rules = array(
            'NewspaperDate' => 'unique:newspaper,date',
            'PublishDate' => 'required',
            'NoOfPages' => 'required'
        );
```

It should check for unique for the coloumn `NewspaperDate`.

Make the coloumn `NewspaperDate` as Unique in the Database